# Java regex placing @ in character classes

Tags: java, regex

I'm using the following code to evaluate a regex expression in Java, which works just fine.

```
public class RegExTest {

  public RegExTest() {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9/.@_-]");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("john.connor3@resistance-aloha.net");
      System.out.println(matcher.find());

  }

}
```

But when I move the '@' sign in above regexp to the end to the character group, as in

```
[^A-Za-z0-9/._-@]
```

, I get the following exception:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 15
[^A-Za-z0-9/._-@]
               ^
```

Why is the position of the '@' character within the character group relevant and how come the regex causes an exception if the '@' character comes before the closing ']'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the `@` that's the problem, it's the hyphen (`-`).

Within a class (`[]`), the hyphen defines a range such as `a-z`.

In your second instance, the range between `_` and `@` is of course invalid, hence the error.

You can escape the hyphen to fix this if you need to: `\\-`.

Comment: thanks for your help. I've tried escaping the hyphen which fixes the exception, but now all unit tests fail for test strings that contain a hyphen, like "john-connor". I've tried both of the following regexes:   [^A-Za-z0-9/-/._@] and [^A-Za-z0-9//-/._@] . Unit tests for test strings like "john.connor3" are working, though. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: @rexford I can't tell by the information you've posted, you would need to post some unit tests with this `Pattern` into another question as the scope is different. On the other hand, I would recommend checking the vast literature (SO and not SO) on parsing e-mail addresses with regex first.

Comment: @rexford, you have your escape sequence backwords in your comment, `[^A-Za-z0-9/._\\-@]`

Comment: @hwnd: that was the last piece in the puzzle. Now, everything's working fine! Thanks to all of you for your help and patience...

Answer (score 2):

It's because the hyphen (`-`) needs to be escaped here.

```
[^A-Za-z0-9/._\\-@]
```

Within a character class, you can place a hyphen as the **first** or **last** character in the range. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to escape it in order to be matched.

Answer (score 1):

`-` is a special character in character classes, it indicates a range.

Your regex therefore contains the range `_-@` which is not valid. You need to escape hte `-`, like so `\-`:

```
"[^A-Za-z0-9/.@_\\-]"
```